# Dynamically printing several arrays from a dictionary as separated strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I'm farely new to objective-C and got a question regarding dictionaries, arrays and tables.

**The situation:**
I got a JSON dictionary containing data. I can access this data via keys, i.e.:

```
NSString = *myString [jsonDict valueForKey:@"somestring"];
```

**Some of those dictionary items though contain arrays instead of a simple string and this is where my trouble starts.**

```
[jsonDict valueForKey:@"someArrays"];
```

...contains a dynamical amount of Arrays (with one value each). I want to print these arrays out as strings in a list with bulletpoints *(in HTML I would use an ul)*. I was told that the best way to do so would be by printing each array into a tableView/ tableView cell?

Personally I don't care what method is the best - I only need some method that works.
**How am I supposed to print these arrays as single strings?**

My current attempt looks like this:

```
  NSArray *arrayData = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"arrays"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayData count]; i++) {
       NSString *arrayStrings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"\u2022", arrayData[i]];
    }
```

But this will only print out the very last Array in valueForKey:@"arrays" as a string.
The rest ist missing (I guess that's because I try to assign all of the arrays to only one string ("arrayStrings"). As a beginner I really can't imagine a right way to do this.

**What do I have to do in order to complete this task efficiently?**

Comment: Very well written question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes guessed right, you are resetting the string in each iteration. Try this:

```
NSString *arrayStrings = [arrayData componentsJoinedByString: @"\r\u2022"];
NSLog(@"%@", arrayStrings);
```

Or this:

```
NSMutableString *arrayStrings = [NSMutableString new];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayData count]; i++) {
    [arrayStrings appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"\r\u2022", arrayData[i]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", arrayStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed setting the same string each time, so logging (`NSLog`) it would show only the last entry.

You "should" try and log in your for loop to make sure you're really getting all the string you need. This would print all your strings.

Now if you wanna store it, i suggest you use an array, like the following.

```
// Preparing my array of strings

NSMutableArray *allTheString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *arrayData = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"arrays"];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayData count]; i++) {

   // According to your code, this gets you your correct log

   NSString *arrayStrings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"\u2022", arrayData[i]];
   [allTheStrings addObject:arrayStrings]
   // Because you just added it above, it is last in the array.
   // You could addObjectAtIndex:i instead, and then log the objectAtIndex:i, 
   // but it's really the same if you start with an empty array
  NSLog(@"This is my string : %@", [allTheStrings lastObject])
}
```

To get your strings from the array, i'm sure you know of `[allTheStrings objectAtIndex:#]`, `#` being an index (0, 1, 3, .. etc)